# Use Parent Table Id to Insert Data into Child Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two tables fournisseur(provider) and facture(bill) in my database.

I want to insert the bill of a selected provider by choosing the provider in my options list and his payment, then I fill the form and click on submit to save the provider's bill data into his table bill.
[bill form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpnwj.png)

When I run my form and fill the form then click on ajouter(add) that error displays [error display after click on add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj8RT.png)

This is my php code to process the data and save it into the database :

```html
<?php 

include 'function/db.php';

if (isset($_POST['selection_fourni']) && isset($_POST['selection_mod_reg'])) {
  
  $selection_fourni = $_POST['selection_fourni'];

  $selection_mod_reg = $_POST['selection_mod_reg'];

}

if (isset($_POST['ajouter'])) {

  $num_fac = $_POST['num_facn'];
  $date_depn = $_POST['date_depn'];
  $date_echn = $_POST['date_echn'];

  $chercher = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM facture WHERE id_fourni = :idfourni AND id_mod_reg = :idmodreg');

  $chercher -> execute(array('idfourni' => $selection_fourni, 'idmodreg' => $selection_mod_reg));

  if ($chercher) {
    

  $ajouter_fac = $db -> prepare('INSERT INTO facture (num_fac, date_depot, date_ech) VALUES (:numfac, :datedepot, :dateech) WHERE id_fourni = :idfourni AND id_mod_reg = :idmodreg');

  $ajouter_fac -> execute(array( 'numfac' => $num_fac, 'datedepot' => $date_depn, 'dateech' => $date_echn, 'idfourni' => $selection_fourni, 'idmodreg' => $selection_mod_reg));

  }
}

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ============================== css ==============================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- =================================================================================-->
 <title>Fournisseur</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default"><!-- début de la barre de navigation -->

        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b> QuickCash: </b>Application comptable</a>

          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

          <!-- **************** LEFT SIDE NAV **********************************-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="fournisseurA.php">Fournisseur</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mode de reglement</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="factureA.php">Facture</a></li>
            </ul>
          <!-- *****************************************************************-->

            <!-- **************** RIGHT SIDE NAV ***********************-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="factureA.php">Ajouter</a></li>
              <li><a href="factureM.php">Modifier</a></li>
              <li><a href="factureS.php">Supprimer</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- *******************************************************-->
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->

     </nav>

   <div class="jumbotron">

    <form method="post">

    <div class="row">
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <label for="id_fourni"> Selectionner le fournisseur</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="selection_fourni" id="id_fourni">
          <?php 

          $list_fourni = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM fournisseur');

          while ($data = $list_fourni -> fetch()) {
            ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $data['id_fourni']; ?>"><?php echo $data['nom_fourni']; ?></option>

            <?php
          }
           ?>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <label for="id_fourni"> Selectionner son mode de paiement</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="selection_mod_reg" id="id_fourni">
          <?php 

          $list_mod_reg = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM mode_reglement');

          while ($data = $list_mod_reg -> fetch()) {
            ?>

              <option value="<?php echo $data['id_mod_reg']; ?>"><?php echo $data['libelle_mod']; ?></option>

            <?php
          }
           ?>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="num_fac">Numero facture</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_fac" name="num_facn" placeholder="Entrez le numero de la facture">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date_dep">Date depot</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_dep" name="date_depn">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Date echéance</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_ech" name="date_echn">
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="ajouter">Ajouter</button></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="Annuler">Annuler</button></li>
    </ul>

    </form>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- ========================================= Javascript ======================================== -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- ============================================================================================= -->
</body>
</html><?php 

include 'function/db.php';

if (isset($_POST['selection_fourni']) && isset($_POST['selection_mod_reg'])) {
  
  $selection_fourni = $_POST['selection_fourni'];

  $selection_mod_reg = $_POST['selection_mod_reg'];

}

if (isset($_POST['ajouter'])) {

  $num_fac = $_POST['num_facn'];
  $date_depn = $_POST['date_depn'];
  $date_echn = $_POST['date_echn'];

  $chercher = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM facture WHERE id_fourni = :idfourni AND id_mod_reg = :idmodreg');

  $chercher -> execute(array('idfourni' => $selection_fourni, 'idmodreg' => $selection_mod_reg));

  if ($chercher) {
    

  $ajouter_fac = $db -> prepare('INSERT INTO facture (num_fac, date_depot, date_ech) VALUES (:numfac, :datedepot, :dateech) WHERE id_fourni = :idfourni AND id_mod_reg = :idmodreg');

  $ajouter_fac -> execute(array( 'numfac' => $num_fac, 'datedepot' => $date_depn, 'dateech' => $date_echn, 'idfourni' => $selection_fourni, 'idmodreg' => $selection_mod_reg));

  }
}

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ============================== css ==============================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- =================================================================================-->
 <title>Fournisseur</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default"><!-- début de la barre de navigation -->

        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b> QuickCash: </b>Application comptable</a>

          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

          <!-- **************** LEFT SIDE NAV **********************************-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="fournisseurA.php">Fournisseur</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mode de reglement</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="factureA.php">Facture</a></li>
            </ul>
          <!-- *****************************************************************-->

            <!-- **************** RIGHT SIDE NAV ***********************-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="factureA.php">Ajouter</a></li>
              <li><a href="factureM.php">Modifier</a></li>
              <li><a href="factureS.php">Supprimer</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- *******************************************************-->
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->

     </nav>

   <div class="jumbotron">

    <form method="post">

    <div class="row">
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <label for="id_fourni"> Selectionner le fournisseur</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="selection_fourni" id="id_fourni">
          <?php 

          $list_fourni = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM fournisseur');

          while ($data = $list_fourni -> fetch()) {
            ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $data['id_fourni']; ?>"><?php echo $data['nom_fourni']; ?></option>

            <?php
          }
           ?>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <label for="id_fourni"> Selectionner son mode de paiement</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="selection_mod_reg" id="id_fourni">
          <?php 

          $list_mod_reg = $db -> query('SELECT * FROM mode_reglement');

          while ($data = $list_mod_reg -> fetch()) {
            ?>

              <option value="<?php echo $data['id_mod_reg']; ?>"><?php echo $data['libelle_mod']; ?></option>

            <?php
          }
           ?>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="num_fac">Numero facture</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_fac" name="num_facn" placeholder="Entrez le numero de la facture">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date_dep">Date depot</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_dep" name="date_depn">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Date echéance</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_ech" name="date_echn">
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="ajouter">Ajouter</button></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="Annuler">Annuler</button></li>
    </ul>

    </form>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- ========================================= Javascript ======================================== -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- ============================================================================================= -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change my insert into SQL

```html
$ajouter_fac = $db -> prepare('INSERT INTO facture (num_fac, date_depot, date_ech, id_fourni, id_mod_reg) VALUES (:numfac, :datedepot, :dateech, :idfourni, :idmodreg)');

  $ajouter_fac -> execute(array( 'numfac' => $num_fac, 'datedepot' => $date_depn, 'dateech' => $date_echn, 'idfourni' => $selection_fourni, 'idmodreg' => $selection_mod_reg));
```

I wish it helps others in need.

Thanks